# Get difference between last and previous number

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have this function which parse a value received on mqtt. The value is actually a timestamp send by an arduino and is number like 1234 , 1345 etc...

```
var parts = msg.payload.trim().split(/[ |]+/);
var update = parts[10];
msg.payload = update;
return msg;
```

What i want is actually instead last value (which is update variable in my case) is to get difference between last received value and previous one.
Basically if I receive 1234 and then 1345, I want to remember 1234 and the value returned by function to be 1345 - 1234 = 111.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide an actual code example/snippet?  What does a `msg` look like?  Are you just trying to return the delta between two timestamps?

Comment: What have you actually tried to achieve this? Should be pretty easy with a second variable to track the last value.

Comment: Yes basically i want  delta between 2 timestamps. I know I need a second variable to keep in mind last value which became previous on next reading but i don t know where to declare it...

Comment: That's something you'd want to declare and store in some internal state or something that remains in context for the duration of code execution. As @basic mentions, finding the diff between two numbers is extremely trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a value to compare to later you need to look at how to use [context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context) to store it.

The context is normally an in memory store for named variables, but it is backed by an API that can be used to persist the context between restarts.

Comment: thanks a lot. this was actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to suggest an alternative approach. Node-RED has a few core nodes that are designed to work across sequences and for this purpose, they keep an internal buffer. One of these nodes is the batch node. Some use cases, like yours,  can take advantage of this functionality to store values thus not requiring using context memory. The flow I share below uses a batch node configured to group two messages in a sequence, meaning it will always send downstream the current payload and the previous one. Then a join node will work on such sequence to reduce the payload to a single value, that is the difference between the timestamps. You need to open the configuration dialog for each node to fully understand how to set up those nodes to achieve the desired goal. I configured the join node to apply a fix-up expression to divide the payload by one thousand, so you get the value in seconds (instead of milliseconds).

[image]

Flow:

```
[{"id":"3121012f.c8a3ce","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"2ab0e0ba.9bd5f","type":"batch","z":"3121012f.c8a3ce","name":"","mode":"count","count":"2","overlap":"1","interval":10,"allowEmptySequence":false,"topics":[],"x":310,"y":280,"wires":[["342f97dd.23be08"]]},{"id":"17170419.f6b98c","type":"inject","z":"3121012f.c8a3ce","name":"","topic":"timedif","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":160,"y":280,"wires":[["2ab0e0ba.9bd5f"]]},{"id":"342f97dd.23be08","type":"join","z":"3121012f.c8a3ce","name":"","mode":"reduce","build":"string","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","key":"topic","joiner":"\\n","joinerType":"str","accumulate":false,"timeout":"","count":"","reduceRight":false,"reduceExp":"payload-$A","reduceInit":"0","reduceInitType":"num","reduceFixup":"$A/1000","x":450,"y":280,"wires":[["e83170ce.56c08"]]},{"id":"e83170ce.56c08","type":"debug","z":"3121012f.c8a3ce","name":"Debug 1","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":600,"y":280,"wires":[]}]
```